# installing rpm without internet connection

Tags: internet, rpm, opensuse

i have successfully installed opensuse 11.3 and some packages with yast.

i have also installed autodesk maya 2009 rpm package.
now the problem is when i try to install autodesk maya rpm package it connects to the internet and download some dependency files.

but how should i do the process on a machine with no internet connection??
as all our workstations doesnot have internet connectivity
can i download those dependencies manually and point yast to such from a particular location.

any help is much appreciated

thanks

update:
i installed with without net connection and pointing yast to opensuse dvd and it installed but never search for any dependencies.
and the application in being started too.
but when i install the rpm with internet connected it downloads a lots of other files and marks them for installation too.
you can check this [image](http://tinypic.com/r/2d1ql9z/7)
check the dependencies for the selected package(maya) too.
will there be a problem if i only install maya without all the other pacages selected ?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15239.html) solution from Novell may be what you're looking for.

Comment: which solution are you referring to?

Comment: The one I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get rpm-packages for all those dependencies you can just install them via "rpm --install package-name.rpm" as root. See the man pages for details.